# Can't add reference to project, Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have created a project container In Visual studio. In this container, I have added three projects: A class library, a ASP .NET MVC Application and a Unit Test application.

Now, Im trying to add references between this projects. When Im trying to add a reference to my class library from my .NET MVC Application, I get an error that says that the reference could not be added.

Why do I get this error? Why can't I add a reference from my class library, to my mvc application?

Comment: What are the .NET versions of the projects?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları: .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: I had an issue similar to this when i accidentally added a portable testing class. Make sure .net targets are then same.

Comment: @Spaceman: When Im trying to view the properties of my class library, I can't see the target framework for the class library.

Comment: Anyone who can help me?

Comment: @Bryan Are you trying add reference to the DLL or .csproject?

Comment: @Kamo: To the project

Comment: To see the target framework, right click on the project >> Properties >> Application tab >> target framework. Anyway what error you are getting exactly?.

Comment: @Yogi: A reference to 'SportsStore.domain' could not be added

Comment: Mus I copy any dll-files? The type of class library that I add to my project Is a Class Library (Package)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference you really need to tell the versions on what you're using : Visual Studio?, ASP.NET MVC?, and .net Framework? as Ufuk mentioned.  I'll assume you mean ASP.NET 5 vNext, as I know this has an issue.

Firstly, look at other posts: [Issue adding reference to class library project in ASP.NET 5 (Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804623/issue-adding-reference-to-class-libary-project-in-asp-net-5-vnext)

And secondly, if it's similar to what I experienced, there appears to be a bug in the beta7, so try adding a file reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32399377/2537017

(That's assuming you've removed the dnxcore50 so it can use the new class library).

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem, and I found it's cause of post build setting on referred library project, **in post build I was copying some un-managed native dll into output directory,** by removing the post build event my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The sibling project was not visible in the Add Reference dialog when trying to add to the related project. Through a random route, I discovered that the project I was working in had a signed assembly, while the project I was trying to add as reference was unsigned. This is not allowed, but there was no indication that there was a problem with the project in the dialog. It was simply not visible.