# COM interop in ASP.5 projects

Tags: .net, com, asp.net-core

The context is an ASP.NET 5 (RC1 at the moment) application, so using `project.json` for references and `.xproj` for Visual Studio. The application targets the full .NET 4.6 framework only (no .net Core support).

I need to use third-party services, which are exposed as COM interfaces.

What is the best way to add them to my project? I couldn't find any information about that.

My intuition is that I'll need to create a "classic" .net dll that uses the COM component, using `csproj` and the "old" build tools, etc. And then reference that dll as a binary reference from my ASP.NET 5 project.

Does that seem right? Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any support for adding com references to the new project system. File a feature request on github.

Comment: Thanks David. I won't create a feature request as I don't care much for COM and I don't think it fits well with the portable .net Core philosophy. Referencing another dll is fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/27198637/3757876 it looks like you need to create a Nuget package for your com component.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037222) addresses using your com component as a dll.

I used [Nuget Package Explorer](https://docs.nuget.org/create/using-a-gui-to-build-packages) to pack my dll up as a nugget package.

After that, I created a local Nuget repository that my project pulls from.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, you don't need Nuget packages to reference binary dll. You can reference them as project dependencies, if you create a special kind of project that looks like this: `{
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": {
      "bin": { "assembly": "My.dll" }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: The question was not about referencing dlls but more about how to add **COM** into the new project system. From your answer I assume that you'd follow the same solution that I outlined: create a .net 4.6 DLL the old-school way (csproj) and reference that binary?